# What is this biplane?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification, biplane

[image]

What is this biplane shown above?

Comment: Welcome to Avaiation.SE! You seem to have a grip of how this site work, though if you haven't already done so, could I suggest reading the [help] and maybe take the [tour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour). To improve your question, could you provide some context on where you found/saw this image?

Answer (score 21):

### [Blackburn T.5 Ripon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackburn_Ripon)

> The Blackburn T.5 Ripon was a British carrier-based torpedo bomber and reconnaissance biplane which first flew in 1926. It was used by the Fleet Air Arm as a torpedo bomber from 1930 until 1935. Ripons were also sold to Finland, where they continued to be used in action in the Winter War and the Continuation War until 1944.

[image]
(Source: [iwm.org.uk](http://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/205212400)) The exact one, number 4 on the side.

> A Blackburn Ripon Mk.IIA torpedo bomber of No 811 Squadron touches down on the flight deck of the fleet aircraft carrier HMS FURIOUS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume the number 4 just means it is the fourth aircraft in that squadron.  I believe the Baffin aircraft superseded the Ripon so it could even be the same squadron.

Comment: Thank you Mike for the information. It is a photograph that I have found in my father in law who passed on in 2009. My wife tells me his older brother was in the RAF  but this is a photo from a local company in Bognor where they lived .The photo is not very clear but I noticed the number behind the large 4 ends in 74. Unfortunately the wing strut gets in the way . Nevertheless it is fascinating reading about this plane and what role they had to play mid wars.. Again many thanks for your help. I use to go to Biggin Hill air shows when I was a lad and still see a Spitfire down at Bognor W Sussex